# IronPython access .NET instances

Tags: python, ironpython, python.net

I developed a .NET application. It includes WinForms and public classes. I would like to add python scripting support for my application, so user can interactively access already created .NET class instances. I see IronPython maybe a good choice. I have played with it and found it can easily call my .NET dll classes but I cannot find a way to access the .NET instances. An instance would already include user inputs.

Could anyone share your experience in embedding python into .NET application and how my objective can be achieved?

Thank you,

Hailiang